# JHipster AWS Deploy Succeed, but Tomcat Answers 404 to All Requests

Tags: amazon-web-services, tomcat, amazon-ec2, jhipster

Friday headache is back again \o/ !

After some fiddling with AWS Console and the jhipster aws sub-generator I somehow managed to deploy my app "succesfully", but still, the tomcat running on my EC2 is returning a 404 http error on every single request I make.

From what I understood, every vital variable in my application-prod.yml is changed by the subgenerator using environment variables for the deploy, so that's probably not the problem.

I checked the java version I compile against it's 1.8, and the tomcat is 8.0, so the known issues of a mismatch between java version is a no-go.

I ran out of ideas on what can be wrong here...

An idea someone ? :)

Edit 06/03/2017:

Here is the catalina startup log

[Link to logs](http://quailshillstudio.com/catalinaLogs/log.out)

Comment: Please give more details. JHipster version, log of app startup, ...

Comment: Also make sure the Tomcat is running with Java 8.  I'm not sure how you are managing it, but for example the "latest" Tomcat 8 docker image still uses JRE 7

Comment: Thanks for the replies. :) I checked the JVM, it's indeed a Java 8. Concerning the logs, I scrolled through them, and I were not able to find anything JHipster related, no errors and no welcome message whatsoever. Do you know where I can find logs of Jhipster startup in a tomcat environment ?